# How to make `pub build` pick up javascript & css files from packages

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Using `pub build` will pick up `packages/browser/dart.js` but it won't pick up javascript files included from other libraries. How can you make `pub build` pick up those external javascript & css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put that files in [assets](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/assets-and-transformers.html).

On a discussion about *Assets-only Pub Packages* [Bob Nystrom gave some explaination](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/E0ooS5Xlb64/F0gdJtPUbuMJ) about *browser package* and `pub build`:

> It has some gross special-case code to handle the JS files in the browser package. That's been in there since before the idea of an "asset" directory existed, and it got Grandfathered in.

Comment: Alexandre so pub packages should put css & js files into the assets folder. So when someone depends on it and does a `pub build` those files will be copied over to the build/web/packages folders correctly?  Sounds like "yes" by reading the thread, just wanted to be verbose about the current solution.

Comment: Regarding [How to refer to assets](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/assets-and-transformers.html#how-to-refer-to-assets) you need to use `/assets/<pkg_name>/<path>`.